# android multi language approach - best practices

Tags: android, input, localization, keyboard

I am trying to determine the best approach on Android for supporting multiple languages.  I understand how resource folders work, and how they get selected when the activity loads and/or has a configuration change.  I also have seen a technique of creating a new locale, assigning it as the default, and broadcasting a config change.  This works.  But I get the impression from this thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/_ZGOTHwzl-w) and the answers from the google framework team this way of doing things is not recommended / supported.  So my questions are:

1. What is the recommended way to support multi languages on the fly without sending the user to the OS menus for language selection?
2. Same question for keyboard input.
3. Finally, I see on my Motorola Xoom when I ask the Locale class for supported languages an impressive list.  For instance, ja-JP, which I've tested and seen allows me to display Japanese chars.  However there is no SIP for this language on the device.  Can I download new keyboards to my platform in these cases?  It just seems odd to me that the platform would support displaying many more languages than it could input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the system do the work.
A user with a language and a keyboard selected in settings will just expect the same conditions from your app.

As far as I knew, there's no better approach as the strings.xml in the different values folders.

Comment: Thanks, Jose.  I certainly appreciate the idea of letting the system do the work.  However in this case the app runs on a tablet locked behind a kiosk.  The menu buttons on the bottom of the display are entirely blocked by the physical enclosure.  The customer doesn't want people walking up and changing the default language on the device as a whole.  Hopefully that makes sense.  Also even if I do fire the language selection menu intent without a back key the user can't navigate out of the menu so we really need to keep them inside our app.

Comment: Here's a pretty straightforward tutorial for that.
http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html